# How to remove overflow (scroller bars) of an overlay image viewer

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, overflow, overlays

Removing the overflow (scroller bars x and y) of the overlay when it's open, and then once the overlay (image viewer) is closed, body makes the overflow visible (scrollers bars x and y)
(obviously before the overlay is triggered by click on an image, the scroller of the body are visible.

example:

```
<style type="text/css">
body { overflow:visible;}
div.overlay {position: fixed; overflow-y:hidden; overflow-x:hidden;} </style>
```

Thanks, I know. I'm shit at coding  :?

Comment: What is your real question here? You have set overflow of the body to visible so it will always be visible. If you don't want that you should change it to hidden.

Comment: @JeevanJose My aim is remove the overflow of the body when the overlay is up. when the overlay is close the ovetflow is visible again.

Comment: @JeevanJose Am I making any sense?

Comment: Yea, you do now :) Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery to do this. Where you initialize your overlay, add this:

```
$("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
```

Where you close the overlay, add this:

```
$("body").css("overflow", "visible");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Brilliant Dude, This helped a million, Can i contact you via twitter?

Comment: I'm following you Via Twitter, Follow back :)